# "Failed to sign" error when trying to create Windows store app package

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am struggling with this weird error all day.
I have developed a Windows store (Metro) app and successfully created an app package in the past.

But suddenly today, I can't create the app package and get an error message that says: `Failed to sign 'C:\Users\XX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XX\AppPackages\XX_1.0.2.5_AnyCPU_Test\XX_1.0.2.5_AnyCPU.appx'. SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.`
The error details points me to the file Microsoft.AppXPackage.targets to the following line: `<SignAppxPackage AppxPackageToSign="@(FinalAppxPackageItem)"`

Who can I fix that and create the app package? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check http://peterdn.com/post/To-make-a-Metro-Appx-Package-from-scratch-you-must-first-e280a6.aspx

Comment: will [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/f25939fb-c48c-4bd0-938e-6a0afbd2dca0) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing helped, finally I solved it by creating a completely new app, and then copying the files from the original app. The problem remained, so I have started to exclude folders from the project until I have found an unneeded folder that created the problem for some reason...

Finally fixed!

Comment: Were you able to determine what's the problem in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Did you applied the visual Studio 2012 update 2 ?
In this recent service pack (begenning if this month), their is some changes related to the app certifications. Anyway the upgrade could resolve your issue.